# CheckBox value in different file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I need to access the checkbox value in a different program. Check box is initiated in ToolDlg.cpp

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CalculateTBA, m_CalculateTBA);
```

in the oninitdialog  initiated like this:

```
    m_CalculateTBA.SetCheck(0);
    CalculateAnalyticTBA = false;


void CToolDlg::OnBnClickedCheck3()
{   
    CalculateAnalyticTBA = m_CalculateTBA.GetCheck();   
}
```

I need checkbox value in SetCal.cpp program. Here is the code i am trying in this program:

```
 CToolDlg dialog;
 if( dialog.CalculateAnalyticTBA )
{

  Do some thing

}
```

But the dialog.CalculateAnalyticTBA  is always tru even though i don't check the check box.
Plz let me know if you need any other info. Thanx for help.

Comment: Is `m_calculateTBA` a `CButton`? Another detail: `GetCheck()` does give an `int` as return which possible values are: `BST_UNCHECKED`, `BST_CHECKED` and `BST_INDETERMINATE`; I noticed you seem to be assigning it to a boolean variable. I bet you are missing a call to `UpdateData(TRUE)` somewhere; you are not changing nothing on the `m_CalculateTBA` — that you associated with checkbox on the `DDX_Control` line — until you call `UpdateData(TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating a dialog, and never showing it. So `CalculateAnalyticTBA` has whatever value you gave it in the constructor of your `CToolDlg` class (or, if you didn't, whatever value the compiler gave it).

In order for this value to be set you must at least *create* the dialog so that the Data Exchange code (which invokes the `DDX_Control` and handles the binding of the checkbox and the variable) has a chance to run.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more?  i thought this code will set the value for CalculateAnalyticTBA void CToolDlg::OnBnClickedCheck3() { CalculateAnalyticTBA = m_CalculateTBA.GetCheck(); }

Comment: Using CalculateAnalyticTBA = m_CalculateTBA.GetCheck(); it gets true value when i check the check box. Which i am accessing in the SetCal.cpp. If i don't check it's still true. Sorry, can you explain little bit more? Thank You

Comment: You can read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14510/Dialog-Data-Exchange-in-MFC. It's not easy to give you a "short" answer that will correctly and adequately explain everything and fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to create and display the CToolDlg dialog and wait for the user to select his choices then only process the choices when the user finally click the "OK" button.

```
CToolDlg dialog;
// create and display the dialog
if (dialog.DoModal()==IDOK)
{  // user clicked the ok button, now do the work
   ....
}
```